# Quick Sort on C++ vector

Tags: c++, quick-sort

I've seen other implementations around, but they seem pretty complicated. This seems to work for me, but is there anything I'm missing? Also, any tips on how I can improve the quality of the code is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Iter>
void quickSort(std::vector<typename Iter::value_type>& vec, Iter left, 
    Iter right) {

    auto size = std::distance(left, right);
    if (size <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    auto pivot = std::next(right, -1);
    if (size == 2 && *pivot < *left) {
        std::iter_swap(left, pivot);
    }
    auto wall = left;
    auto curr = left;

    while (curr != right) {
        if (*curr < *pivot) {
            std::iter_swap(wall, curr);
            wall++;
        }
        curr++;
    }

    std::iter_swap(pivot, wall);
    quickSort(vec, left, wall);
    quickSort(vec, wall + 1, right);

}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myVec = { 6, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 34, 2434, 251, 4, 12, 4, 5,
        634, 523, 5, 4, 353, 3, 5, 345, 7, 86786, 8, 7, 9, 1 };
    quickSort(myVec, myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I seem to remember having seen quicksort before, even Lomuto partitioning, *and* a tag for things done time and again: [tag:reinventing-the-wheel].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't need to pass the vector itself. `left` and `right` iterators provide all the necessary information.

  That said, you pass a *correct* `right`: too often people pass it as `.end() - 1` which indeed leads to unnecessary complications.
- Partitioning is an important algorithm on its own right and deserves to be factored out.
- The lines

  ```
  if (size == 2 && *pivot < *left) {
      std::iter_swap(left, pivot);
  }
  ```

  serve no purpose. The code works fine without them.
- The trickiest part is achieving best performance.

  - The poor choice of pivot may result in quadratic time complexity. In a professional implementation choosing pivot *is* the most complex part.
  - In general, C++ is very good in eliminating tail recursion, but in this particular case it may use some help. Specifically, you'd want to recurse into smaller partition, and iterate over the larger one.
  - Another optimization is a timely switch to insertion sort. Instead of descending all the way to `size <= 1` it is beneficial to stop recursion earlier (say, when `size <= 16`). Once the recursions are completed, the range is *almost sorted*, and insertion sort runs in linear time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Really insightful. I had to also change the first if statement to if (size <= 2)return; For some reason, instead of throwing a run-time error, Visual Studio just crashes...

Comment: *The special case for `size == 2` serves no purpose* while missing the terminal `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Additions to [vnp's take](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189109/93149):

- code shall be documented. You may find (and justify) (succinct) presentations like yours in *print media*, where it doesn't easily get separated from the explanations due - with *program code*, there's copy&paste. A programming language may or may not have a standard for documenting purpose and limits of a construct. I'm not aware of such for "the C-family", I use&recommend [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).
- must read: templaterex' [How to Implement Classic Sorting Algorithms in Modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650627)
- vnp implied you'd not want to recurse into the larger partition - 
  that is a matter of correctness even more than experiencing (intolerable) run time quadratic in the number of items to sort:
  in the worst case, you'd nest one call per item, possibly hitting a limit on stack space or nesting depth.
- this worst case occurs if picking `pivot` as shown for (almost) pre-ordered items - a deplorably, even disagreeably frequent use case.
- reduce the visual impact of special casing:

  ```
  if (size < QUICK_LIMIT) {
      if (size <= 1) {
          return;
      auto other = std::next(left);
      if (2 == size && *other < *left) {
          std::iter_swap(left, other);
          return;
      }
      // handle 2 < size < QUICK_LIMIT
  }
  ```